# Ajax process and update retun a not updated HTML in JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a commandilnk, that when clicked, update the page. But i cannot update the ui:repeat childs value. Here is my command link:

```
<p:commandLink value="#{bibliotecaDettaglioView.libro.titolo}"
                                       action="#{bibliotecaDettaglioView.refresh}"
                                       process="myX"
                                       update="olProprietario olTitle csValutazione giCopertina olTrama olGenere olAutore olAnno
                                               olIsbn myXXX:itaRecensione myXXX:csVoto myX">


</p:commandLink>
```

Here is the component that i wanna update:

```
<div class="book-state">
<h:form id="myX">
    <h:panelGroup id="panel">
        <ui:repeat id="repeat" value="#{libro.copieLibro}" var="copia">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{copia.formatoLibro}"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="#{copia.idstatoLibro}"/>
            <p:outputLabel styleClass="#{copia.idstatoLibro eq 'd'? 'available' :'unavailable'}" value="#{copia.statoLibro}"/>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

The strange thing is that when i look at the AJAX response in the chrome developer tools, the ajax request returns the html code but with te not updated values..
Here is what i get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form id="myX" name="myX" method="post" action="/biblioteca-dettaglio.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
 <input type="hidden" name="myX" value="myX" />
 <span id="myX:panel">
  <label id="myX:repeat:0:j_idt67" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Cartaceo</label>
  <label id="myX:repeat:0:j_idt116" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">d</label>
  <label id="myX:repeat:0:j_idt68" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget available">Disponibile</label>
  <label id="myX:repeat:1:j_idt67" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">PDF</label>
  <label id="myX:repeat:1:j_idt116" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">d</label>
  <label id="myX:repeat:1:j_idt68" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget available">Disponibile</label>
 </span>
</form>
```

I get the updated values only after a refresh

Comment: Are you sure you want to have the `process` and `update` attributes like this on your `p:commandButton`? Doesn't `process="@form"` (which is the default) and `update="myX"` give you what you want?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes

Comment: I have a lot of components that are outside forms..

Comment: And the command link is outside a form to

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].